# Does PDFTranscoder (org.apache.fop) support hyperlinks?

Tags: java, pdf, svg, apache-fop, batik

I'm trying to convert the SVG document to PDF with the use of Batik (v1.12) and PDFTranscoder (fop v2.4).

The problem is that my SVG contains  links that somehow are not transcoded to PDF. Is it supported, or is there a known issue for it, or am I trying to use it in a wrong way?

Below is SVG markup (the simplest I can reproduce the issue for) of an [input document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kcuqX1CSkYaVJb1pttnGkx-ejUc0dfI-/view?usp=sharing):

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500"
     height="500" x="0" y="0">
    <g>
        <a target="_blank" xlink:href="https://www.google.com">
            <text x="50%" y="50%" style="font: 13px sans-serif"
                  text-anchor="middle" fill="rgb(0, 0, 0)">TEST
            </text>
        </a>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Also simplified code snippet in Java, that I use for transcoding:

```
public void convert(InputStream svgIn, OutputStream pdfOut) throws SvgExportException {
    String                parserName = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
    SAXSVGDocumentFactory factory    = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parserName);

    try {
      Document      document = factory.createDocument("svg", svgIn);
      PDFTranscoder t        = new PDFTranscoder();

      TranscoderInput  input  = new TranscoderInput(document);
      TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(outputStream);

      try {
        transcoder.transcode(input, output);
      } catch (TranscoderException e) {
        throw new SvgExportException("Internal Error: Transcoding the SVG Document to PDF failed.", getReasonForTranscoderException(e));
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new CustomTechnicalException(e);
    }
  }
```

Output PDf document can be viewed [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FBC4XP5csKoJ72Gf9FtzRH0PGhtYKHH4/view). As you see, when hovering a text (and clicking it) there is no link.

Thank you for any help on this!